# NPM package in Angular Typescript - Failed to Compile

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-install, yahoo-finance

I'm just running into a compile error when trying to use the following package in Angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/earnings-calendar-yahoo

I have installed the package and imported it into a service file as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { earnings } from 'earnings-calendar-yahoo';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EarningsCalService {

  constructor() { }

  results(){
    earnings.fetchTheDay()
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

However when I try to serve the website I am getting this issue:

> Failed to compile.
>   ./node_modules/earnings-calendar-yahoo/earningsCalendarYahoo.js 19:16
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (19:16) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
>   configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> // Fetches earnings on a spesific day    fetchTheDay = async (day =
>   this.today) => {
>
> // Sleep if applicable

I am new to Angular so I've tried a few things I have seen on here but to no avail.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you need to inject the service in constructor

Comment: @fastAsTortoise Thanks for the response, just tried this however still getting the same failed to compile.

Comment: may be you are using wrong service also usually classes have uppercase first letter like Earning. you might wanna look into that